# Laravel / Eloquent triple model many-to-many relation

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many, pivot-table

I'm trying to write in Eloquent (Laravel 5.5):

My table structure is as follows

1. products
2. colours
3. sizes
4. colour_product - Pivot table

I have a list of products and colours(Many to many). For every product - colour pair has multiple sizes. I need something like 'colour_product_sizes'. Please suggest a method using Laravel Eloquent.

**Product.php (Product Model)**

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
   use \Dimsav\Translatable\Translatable;
   public $translatedAttributes = ['name','short_description'];


   public function colours()
   {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Colour::class,'colour_product')->withTimestamps();
   }

   public function sizes()
   {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Size::class);
   } 


}

?>
```

**Colour.php (Colour Model)**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Colour extends Model
{
   use \Dimsav\Translatable\Translatable;

   public $translatedAttributes = ['name'];
   protected $fillable = ['code'];

   public function products()
   {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
   }
}
?>
```

**Size.php (Size Model)**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Size extends Model
{

   use \Dimsav\Translatable\Translatable;

   public $translatedAttributes = ['name','short_name','extra'];    
   protected $fillable = ['code'];

   public function products()
   {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
   }

}
?>
```

**colour_product Table Schema**

```
1   id  int(10) UNSIGNED    
2   product_id  int(10) UNSIGNED    
3   colour_id   int(10) UNSIGNED    
4   created_at  datetime    
5   updated_at  datetime
```

Comment: Using HasMany() and connect with id's

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer?

Comment: No, I have solved this by adding a custom function to the model.  

https://gist.github.com/sreejith2base/5783ad978090cb6ff6d737aeb69f2de0 

But still, I am looking for a best practice.

Comment: How/in what context do you use `colourSizes()`?